# VNC server full screen display is too small

Tags: vnc, vncviewer, tigervnc

On a centOS 7 remote server I have installed `tigervnc`. On Windows the viewer I am using is `RealVNC Viewer`.

The configuration at `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@\:1.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

 

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l root -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1920x1080"
PIDFile=/root/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The configuration at `/root/.vnc/config`

```
## Supported server options to pass to vncserver upon invocation can be listed
## in this file. See the following manpages for more: vncserver(1) Xvnc(1).
## Several common ones are shown below. Uncomment and modify to your liking.
##
# securitytypes=vncauth,tlsvnc
# desktop=sandbox
geometry=1980x1080
# localhost
# alwaysshared
```

When I connect to the server, the display is not what I expected. It's simply too small to use.

[image: VNC viewer display]

I have tried changing the scaling but that didn't help. The scaling would help but the remote display is not in the center of the screen. So when I changed the scaling to 200%, it becomes "hidden".

Comment: Shouldn't that be 1920 x 1080?

Comment: @JeremyBoden Thanks for catching that. Unfortunately the problem is still there.